# Spring Boot deserialization snake case to camel case fails. Can't deserialize "some_value" to "someValue"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

So I have this Spring Boot app that has to take a GET request with parameters "some_value=1500&some_other_value=50000" to an object with the attributes someValue and someOtherValue.

I've tried @JsonProperty("some_value") and it didn't work. I've added "spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy=SNAKE_CASE" to my application.properties file and it still doesn't work.

Important detail: when I try to serialize an object it does turn someValue => some_value and someOtherValue => some_other_value. So I know the config is "fine" but it refuses to map the request param in snake case to the camel case that I need. (And no... I have no control over the request format. I get the params in snake case and I have to map them to camel case)

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: I dont think deserialisation is going to work for `GET` requests. It just maps to respective request parameter types or simple a Map of request params. Share your request mapping code.

Comment: I have none... I'm so frustrated that I cleaned it to barebones just for testing.

I get 
`localhost:8080/myApp/users?user=pepe&some_value=1500&some_other_value=50000`

my code is

`@GetMapping("/users")
    public User users(User u){
        return u;
    }`

and that returns `{"user":"pepe","some_value":null,"some_other_value":null}`

Comment: As I said it will not work for GET request. change it to post and send the user json in the request body. ```@PostMapping("/users") public User users(@RequestBody User u){ return u; }```.

Comment: FFS that was it... I honestly don't see why it should work only on post but not on get... that feels counterintuitive. But that was it. Thanks a million I honestly coudln't find any info that specified "this is only for post body and not for get params" Thank you so so so much.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to create a `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`. It is verbose, but you can deal with the query string, inject the ObjectMapper (keeping the same config) and do yourself the conversion.

I created an Annotation to filter which type I wanna handle:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
public @interface QueryStringArgResolver {
}
```

Then created the resolver:

```
@Component
public class QueryStringArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

...

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(final MethodParameter methodParameter) {
        return methodParameter.getParameterAnnotation(QueryStringArgResolver.class) != null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(final MethodParameter methodParameter,
                                  final ModelAndViewContainer modelAndViewContainer,
                                  final NativeWebRequest nativeWebRequest,
                                  final WebDataBinderFactory webDataBinderFactory) throws Exception {

        final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) nativeWebRequest.getNativeRequest();
        final String json = qs2json(request.getQueryString());
        final Object a = mapper.readValue(json, methodParameter.getParameterType());

        return a;
    }

...
}
```

Usage:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @GetMapping("/some-url")
    public SomeResponse doSomething(@QueryStringArgResolver final SomeQueryStringToBind request) {
        ...
    }
```

BTW, don't forget to register your resolver in this way to be able to inject beans:

```
@Configuration
public class ArgumentResolverConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Autowired
    private QueryStringArgumentResolver argumentResolver;

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(
            final List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        argumentResolvers.add(argumentResolver);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think u have some mistake in configuration , in my case the cause is @EnableWebMvc annotation, if u use this annotation , the default autoconfig from spring boot will not work.

in order to convert attribute from camelCase to snake_case , u only need to override bean `jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` ,spring use this bean to change the snake_case setting for jackson , try these code below add them to ur @Configuration file

```
@Bean
    @Primary
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder() {
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jsonBuilderConfig = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
        jsonBuilderConfig.propertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);
        return jsonBuilderConfig;
    }
```

if u read  `readJavaType()` method which is  under `AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter` class,u can see how jackson works , there is an `objectMapper` there used to convert json.track this objectMapper,if PropertyNamingStrategy doesn`t have snake_case setting the convertion cant work

Comment: I spent ~3 hours testing all the possible ways to change naming strategy to Snake case. None of them worked, and... then I found your answer about @EnableWebMvc annotation. I didn't even know it would have such side effects. Thanks man! Now everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

So @Barath was right you don't get clean deserialized objects from GET params. But There's a workaround. Not sure how **legal** this is or not... but here it goes:

```
@Autowired private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

@GetMapping("/users")
    public User users(@RequestParam Map<String,String> params){
        User u = objectMapper.convertValue(params,User.class);
        return u;
    }
```

That way you still have your GET method and you get all the params deserialized into a nice little object for you to do whatever. Hope this helps anyone. And I hope Spring/Jackson people enable auto-deserialization of GET params the same way it works with POST methods.

Answer (score 0):

First, your request parameters (`some_value=1500&some_other_value=50000`) are mapped to RequestParam, not RequestBody.
Second, jackson library deserializes RequestBody, not RequestParam.
Third, Post or Put http method mapping parameter to body.

So, you are requesting GET method and request parameters and your jackson config does not work to your request parameters.

Camel case parameter, or `@RequestMapping(name="some_param") String someParam` will be mapped to your request paramter.

Comment: I appreciate the response but that was not my problem. I already know those are @RequestParams... and not body... and that if I'm getting a GET request it shouldn't have a body... but I'm not sure what you're even trying to say. If I pass all the parameters that conform to a POJO I get the POJO instance alright... something (if not jackson) is doing the mapping. And ignoring my propertynamestrategies configuration. that was my problem. I already got it working using a workaround in my response. I'm not sure I understand what your point was.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution for a similar problem, but as I have not found any simple, satisfying answer (most of them with a lot of code, or requiring me to change HTTP methods) I have figured out a way that satisfied me.

If you have a controller method like this:

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<Connection> handle(SampleDTO sample)
```

Then you can use `@ConstructorProperties` over constructor in SampleDTO to resolve the issue:

```
public class SampleDTO {
    String testVarOne;
    String testVarTwo;

    @ConstructorProperties({ "test_var_one", "test_var_two" })
    public SampleDTO(String testVarOne, String testVarTwo) {
        this.testVarOne = testVarOne;
        this.testVarTwo = testVarTwo;
}
```

Of course, this works only if you know the request params names. Works for POST an GET methods.