# Spring boot Rest API consume multipart/form-data with snake case

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm using a rest API to consume a multipart/form-data the request including

- String
- Integer,
- List,
- Date (java.util)
- Multipart

but the problem is multipart/form-data is not able to map with snake case in the form-data request parameters.

```
class FormDataRequest {
  private String name;
  private Date createdDate;
  private List<Integer> ids;
  private Multipart filePictureProfile;
  //setter //getter
}

@PostMapping(value = "/registration", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity register(FormDataRequest request) {
   // logger.info(request);
}
```

so I can call via postman but I have to send parameter in camel case, It's must be exact same as the request class (ie: createdDate, filePictureProfile).

I want to send in snake_case like :
{
name:...,
created_date:...,
ids:...
file_picture_profile:...
}

Any suggestion will be appreciated?

Comment: You may check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66887024/3836101

Comment: Hi @Rony Nguyen I face the same problem. Have you found a solution please?

Comment: Nope, I have to use Camelcase @Jedupont

Answer (score -2):

**USE `@JsonProperty`**

*@JsonProperty is used to indicate external property name, name used in data format (JSON or one of other supported data formats)*

hence your `FormDataRequest`

```
     class FormDataRequest {
        @JsonProperty("name")
        private String name;
        @JsonProperty("created_date")
        private Date createdDate;
        private List<Integer> ids;
        @JsonProperty("file_picture_profile")
        private Multipart filePictureProfile;
       //setter //getter
      }
```

Comment: `@ JsonProperty` not working in this case.